# Search for site

Tags: feature-request, questions

I want to be able to search for a site by name. If I want to go to the Spanish exchange I want to be able to type "Spanish" in the search bar. As of now, many other sites show up it if I do this. In fact, if I type, "Espanol" it still does not show up. Fix this please, or tell me where I need to post this.

Comment: Which search bar are you using? The topbar one or the one in the top-right "sandwich" with your communities listed? (yeah, it's SE's logo, but really it looks like a sandwich)

Comment: The one on the top. You might have the answer, if you rewrote this as an answer rather than a question. I would have never looked there.

Comment: Yes, that worked, write that as an answer and you get the check

Comment: @Jenayah ...forgot to "at" you. That is the answer thank you. Write it as an answer to get the check

Comment: ^ No need for a new answer, there are already some in the one I linked just above :) this way all the info stays gathered in one place, etc, etc. Hat tip to Polygeo for bumping it, I searched for the dupe but didn't find it right away. Case closed! :)

Comment: @Jenayah Plus one for first ever "duplicate" that was on point

Comment: @Jenayah this is a good example of where AI base on word matching fails. I did not see the "duplicate" in the suggestions as I typed the question.

Comment: Part of the reason behind closing questions as duplicates is to aid in searchability, as duplicates are useful as signposts to help find the target question in case someone uses the same wording as you and doesn't find it.